# VBA: Write date and some text to a txt file

Tags: excel, vba, text

I'm trying to create a EULA for a VBA program that I've been programming for a few months now, but I've hit a bit of a wall.

Basically, the user clicks a check box, so that it's value becomes true, and a button control sees if the check box's value is true, when the button is clicked/value becomes true. If it is, it will close the EULA window, open the main window, and then it should write to a text file the date and time, and some possible text saying that it was agreed. The code for the button and check box is:

```
    Private Sub eula_agree_button_Click()
    If eula_agree_check_box.Value = True Then
    Unload eula
    main_window.show
    End If
    End Sub
```

That just closes the EULA window and opens the main window, so for the date and time code for the .txt file I constructed this:

```
    Private Sub eula_agree_button_Click()
    If eula_agree_check_box.Value = True Then
    Unload eula
    Open "C:\eulalog\eulalog.txt" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".lst" For Output As #1
    Close #1
    Pause 2
    main_window.Show
    Else
    MsgBox "You have not agreed to the EULA. Please read the EULA, then                         
    check the check box, then press the 'I agree' button.", , "EULA Notice"
    End If
    End Sub
```

However; when I run this I receive the following error:

1. The code will stop as normal when it hits an error, and highlights the
       Close #1
   line of code
2. VBA says

> "Run-time error '76': Path not found

I believe this is because it can't find the text file named 'eulalog.txt', although it does exist on the target drive (C:)

Also, if you're asking why the file path is eulalog\eulalog.txt, the first 'eulalog' is the folder, and the second 'eulalog' being 'eulalog.txt' is the text file (.txt being the file extension).

Comment: Why the `& Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".lst"`, if the path is `"C:\eulalog\eulalog.txt"`?

Comment: This is what I thought would print the date and time in the text file. I've been trying to use code samples from online.

Comment: For more detail, see the [`Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) documentation. Just the path name should follow the open statement. You're looking for the [`Write #`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement) statement.

Comment: So change:
    Open "C:\eulalog\eulalog.txt" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".lst" For Output As #1
    Close #1
to
     Write "C:\eulalog\eulalog.txt" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".lst" For Output As #1
    Close #1     

Do I keep the 'Close #1' code?

Comment: Open first, then write, then close. See the code sample in the [`Write #`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Code is now: Private Sub eula_agree_button_Click()
If eula_agree_check_box.Value = True Then
Unload eula
Open "eulalog.txt" For Output As #1
Write #1, "I agree with the End User License Notice and I wish to continue and start Sketchbox - has been valued as true by end-user"
Close #1
Pause 2
main_window.Show
Else
MsgBox "You have not agreed to the EULA. Please read the EULA, then check the check box, then press the 'I agree' button.", , "EULA Notice"
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is:

```
Private Sub eula_agree_button_Click()
If eula_agree_check_box.Value = True Then
Unload eula
Open "eulalog.txt" For Output As #1
Write #1, "I agree with the End User License Notice and I wish to continue and start         Sketchbox - has been valued as true by end-user"
Close #1
Pause 2
main_window.Show
Else
MsgBox "You have not agreed to the EULA. Please read the EULA, then check the check box, then press the 'I agree' button.", , "EULA Notice"
End If
End Sub
```

We use the open statement to open the text file, with the file and it's extension (.txt) in speech marks

```
    Open "test.txt" For Output As #1
```

We then write to the .txt file opened by typing

```
   Write #1
```

the '#1' being what we are referencing
then add the text we what so it looks like

```
    Write #1, "Hello World"
```

then we close the text file by typing

```
    Close #1
```

The rest of my code is for the application but what I've just listed it what works fine.

The full code is:

```
    Open "test.txt" For Output As #1
    Write #1, "Hello World"    
    Close #1
```

All you need to do is change the filename from 'test.txt' to your .txt file name and the text in the speech marks to whatever you want it to put in your text file :)

Hope this helps any one else out there :)